# Is there a way to use My Wallet account with bitcoin-qt client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain.info

I have some funds on My Wallet account (Blockchain.info) and I'd like to have a possibility to use them with my bitcoin-qt client. Is there a possibility to do that? Please give short description. I get many "Yes" answears on some forum but still can not do that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, export the private key(s) of the addresses that have funds on blockchain.info using the settings/advanced section and then import them into the bitcoin-qt software. You will then have full access to the address(es) in both wallets.

in the bitcoin-qt debug console..

```
importprivkey "keyhere"
```

Edit:  Don't forget change from transactions may not go back into the original address - so once you've made a transaction it may be that you have to repeat the export & import private key process to have the funds available on both wallets.

Comment: What George proposes is correct, however after you successfully import the keys to your `reference client` wallet you should immediately delete them from `blockchain.info`, as maintaining the same private keys in more than one active wallets could soon result in weird behavior and unexpected errors, eg if your `ref client` is not fully synched when you spend in `blockchain.info` the output of one of the imported keys and then you try to send another tx from your `reference client` which attempts to spend this very output (`double spend`) then your `ref client` wallet will become corrupted.

Comment: I don't think it would corrupt anything, I've successfully shared keys many times. Though I always wait for everything to sync. There is a chance of a double spend but assuming you don't try to double spend and wait for sync you'll be fine.

Comment: @George just because it never happened to you it doesn't mean that this will always be the case for all clients that share parts of their wallets across the network. What if this wallet is controlled by some third-party RPC client that cannot itself realize that it's out of synch and its coin selection algorithm decides to spend an already-spent by another synched wallet with shared keys, what would happen in that case, how would the `reference client` deal with it? How can you be confident that a double spend will not occur when creating offline transactions in a wallet with shared keys?

Comment: What would happen is the transaction would be broadcast as normal, but quickly rejected by the network. It wouldn't corrupt his wallet.dat and he wouldn't lose any of his keys. Sure, the software may not notice until sully sync'd but I honestly don't see how it would corrupt anything.

Comment: @George it wouldn't corrupt the `.dat` file, however it would make the wallet unusable shortly after so please let's stop playing with semantics. Also, please refer to these threads for more on that: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3499/11221, also: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5324.msg77896#msg77896 and:http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/490/can-i-use-my-wallet-on-different-computers/509#509

Comment: semantics? I quote "then your ref client wallet will become corrupted". That comment is the only reason I replied. Anyway, agreed, enough of this thread.